# UICollectionView cells are invisible

Tags: uicollectionviewcell

I recently added a UICollectionView to my storyboard, it's currently pushed into view by another view and this appears to be working fine however, using the storyboard editor i set the view to contain 35 cells which in the editor look fine, but when i run the app the cells are invisible. Some of the cells have UIButtons inside and these don't render either.

To double check the view was rendering i changed the background colour in the editor and ran it again, the colour updated correctly. Am i right in assuming that the setup should automatically render the cells without me having to run any delegate code if they have been setup in the editor?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT----

Ok i have implemented the appropriate delegate methods in my second view controller that then pushes a segue to bring up the collectionview controller, i also added the  to my second view controller header file and added the following code to the .M file:

```
// number of sections for the view
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

// numbers of items in section
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

// cell to return (uses the custom identifier of the cell in the storyboard)
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"quickNoteCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

I have also made sure the identifier in the cell on the storyboard uses the quickNoteCell, and changed its default colour to blue, however i am still not seeing the cell any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jay said, put the line here under your @interface and it should work. Nothing is wrong in the code you posted.

```
<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 11):

You are not seeing any cells because you have generated a UICollectionViewController subclass, which added the following line in `viewDidLoad:`. From my understanding, this produces blank cells that do get compressed to size 0,0 when using autolayout.

**Delete this line to see the cells that you defined in storyboard instead of invisible UICollectionViewCells**

```
 // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource protocols?

Is collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: being called?

Comment: I've not added any code to the delegation protocols, i was under the impression that if the cells are setup in the storyboard and have items inside them (i.e. the UIButton) they should render outright without having to process any code, i'll have a look into the delegation protocols tonight and post my results, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Added a change to my code in my original post, i'm not sure why the cell doesn't display still.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom collectionViewItems and you want to load data from nib file register first nib to collectionView:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: reuseIdentifier, bundle: Bundle.main);
self.collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);
```

and in collection view delegate just call:

```
collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```