# UICollectionView - Not displaying cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

What I'm trying to achieve is a 3x3 table with `UICollectionView`. But it just doesn't display any cells when running the application. It does display the background color of the `CollectionView` though (which I set to blue) Can someone help me here?

What I have done is create a `storyboard` and simply dragged a `CollectionViewController` onto it. This controller also brought a nested `CollectionView` with it. Then I simply used the settings to make its background blue and to add a cell to it of which I made the background purple (both only for testing). Finally dragged a `UILabel` onto it. Now when run it just displays the blue background but no cells even though they are clearly visible in the editor. I've then tried to create a custom `UICollectionViewController`, assign the class to the `CollectionViewController` instead of the standard class and did the same to the cell (assign a custom `UICollectionViewCell`). In the custom `UICollectionViewController` I implemented the following methods:

```
-(NSIntegear)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 9;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AboutYourGoalsMultiSelectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell goal]setText:@"T"];

    return cell;
}
```

I set the identifier of the cell to "Cell" and made an outlet connection of dataSource and delegate between the CollectionView and the custom UICollectionViewController. Everything compiles fine.
So what am I missing? Shouldn't it have displayed something way before doing all these tweaks by simply using the editor?

[image: The storyboard editor with all the changes I did]

Comment: Is the cell identifier for the CollectionViewCell set to "Cell"?

Comment: Yes, Collection Reusable View > Identifier is set to "Cell" and Identity > Restoration ID as well

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me. I'd set a breakpoint in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to a) make sure it's getting called and, b) see what else might be going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't find a direct solution to it I've tried to set up a new project and did the same changes and tweaks and surprisingly, this time,  everything worked from the beginning. I then copied the storyboard to my old project, deleted all the old files and replaced it with the files from the new project. Everything is working good so far. I have no idea what the actual error was but I'm happy it's working now. Thanks to everyone who had a look at my question!

Answer (score 49):

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254891/uicollectionview-cells-are-invisible/29517349#29517349), in short, you need to **delete this line** if you are working with a storyboard:

```
 // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Comment: This was the main reason for it not working for me. XCode inserts this by default when using story boards. Great catch.

Comment: Just adding 
`[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; `

is for programmatically registering cell as documented by apple

[Use either the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method to associate your cell with a reuse identifier. You might call these methods as part of the parent view controller’s initialization process.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html)

Answer (score 6):

A common source of error is that dataSource and delegate are not set in the Outlets

Comment: As I've had to learn right now, another very frustrating error source is AutoLayout: make sure UICollectionView doesn't get squished down to zero size.

Comment: Good hint! You can set the `UICollectionView` size to `CGRect.zero`, but when setting it to a value greater than `CGRect.zero` call `reloadData()` on the collection view to display the cells.

Comment: And if you get a crash about an unrecognized selector, make sure your View Controller has the correct custom class!

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the first line of your code.

```
-(NSIntegear)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

`NSIntegear` should be `NSInteger`.

Not sure if that's the problem though because xcode shouldn't allow you to run your project with this error. I just tried following the exact same steps you mentioned (without the label) but with the above correction and it worked fine for me. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create just a simple CollectionViewController (not custom i.e. by implementation) and your cells are not displaying when application runs just follow the following steps:-

- First of all you have to create the cocoa touch class (if not created) for your UICollectionViewController. FILE -> NEW -> COCOA TOUCH CLASS then choose UICollectionViewController from drop down list of subclass.
- Now under your identity inspector section of your CollectionViewController add your class by choosing from the drop down list of Custom Class.
- Now open your created class and edit your methods like this:

  ```
  override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
  //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
  return 1
   }
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
  return 1
  }
  ```
- Only edit "return" value (which is 0 by  default) just simply write the number of cells/items you want to display or you have created (in this case here i only had created one Cell).

[ios] [swift3] [xcode]